# PoolingLayer[] doesn't export to cloud anymore

Tags: neural-networks, wolfram-cloud, cloud-deploy

Since last week (?) `PoolingLayer[]` appears broken when exported to the cloud from my local machine.

Lets define two nets, one is a poolingLayer and the other a convLayer:

```
net=NetInitialize@NetChain[{PoolingLayer[2,2]},"Input"->{1,64,64}]
net2=NetInitialize@NetChain[{ConvolutionLayer[1,3]},"Input"->{1,64,64}]
```

Local evaluation works fine:

```
net@{RandomReal[1,{64,64}]}  (*gives result*)
net2@{RandomReal[1,{64,64}]}  (*gives result*)
```

However cloud evaluation fails for the poolingLayer net. Oddly enough it works fine when I define the pooling layer in the cloud:

```
CloudEvaluate[NetInitialize[NetChain[{PoolingLayer[2,2]},"Input"->{1,64,64}]][{RandomReal[1,{64,64}]}]]  (*OK*)
CloudEvaluate[net2@{RandomReal[1,{64,64}]}] (*OK*)
CloudEvaluate[net@{RandomReal[1,{64,64}]}] (*$Failed*)
```

This only happened sometime in the last few weeks. I was deploying networks with poolingLayers on a regular basis before that. A workaround seems to be to redefine all poolingLayers in my networks in the cloud before evaluation. Is this a bug?